# rbenv: no such command `init-'

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby in terminal via homebrew.

So far I've entered:

```
brew install rbenv
```

and then I rain

```
rbenv init
```

after the command was run I received

```
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

finally I entered:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I restarted my terminal per instructions and then received

```
rbenv: no such command `init-'
```

at the top of my new terminal.

error messages: rbenv: no such command `init-'

expected messages: nothing, blank terminal

Comment: Please include the relevant line from your `~/.bash_profile` in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The default shell (Bash before macOS 10.15) on **macOS** is a **login** shell. Only `.bash_profile` is used in initialization by default.

You need to put `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` into `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`.

#### Bash init files

1. **login** mode:

   - `/etc/profile`
   - `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only first one that exists)
2. interactive **non-login**:

   - `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
   - `~/.bashrc`
3. **non-interactive**:

   - source file in `$BASH_ENV`

Check the path of the red line for an interactive, login shell on macOS.

[image]

#### References

- [Unix shell initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization#bash)
- [Shell startup scripts](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html)